# Python play mp3/wav file audio(Pygame mixer)

Tags: python, audio, pygame, mp3, wav

What is the best way to play mp3/wav file audio with Python?

I tried to use pygame, it play the sound, but don't close propertly the file. 
So when i try to remove the file i get errors.(Yes, i call pygame.mixer.quit() , but the file is still used in another process)

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using libraries other than `pygame` then you can use [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) which is clean and easy. Below is an working example.

For `wav` files

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

song = AudioSegment.from_wav("your_wav_file.wav")
play(song)
```

For `MP3` files

```
song = AudioSegment.from_mp3("your_mp3_file.mp3")
play(song)
```